# Can't install Lineage OS due to outdated bootloader on Moto G 2013 XT1034 falcon

Tags: bootloader, motorola-moto-g, lineageos

I just bought a Moto G XT1034 and I'm trying to install Lineage OS 14.1 (lineage-14.1-20170307-nightly-falcon-signed.zip). I'm following the wiki instructions (http://wiki.lineageos.org/falcon_install.html). I successfully unlocked the bootloader and installed the custom recovery (Team Win Recovery Project) but when I try to install the new OS I get the following error message:

`This package supports bootloader(s): 0x4118, 0x4119, 0x411A; this device has bootloader unknown.`

Apparently my bootloader version is 4105:

`$ fastboot getvar version-bootloader
version-bootloader: 4105`

How can I overcome this issue? Should I update my bootloader? Is there a safe way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following [these](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/5ycv9y/cant_install_lineage_os_due_to_outdated/derjah0/) instructions to flash a newer stock ROM with a up to date bootloader and installed Lineage OS afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Use [this tool](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/falcon-bootloader-upgrader-tool-t3093793) to upgrade your bootloader to a compatible version.

You should also update your TWRP to the latest version, as older versions aren't compatible with the new bootloader either, and will display a moving line across the screen if you insist.

After these steps you are clear to proceed to flashing LOS 14.1.

Comment: I didn't upgraded yet. I'm using TWRP version 3.0.2-2 (seems to be the most up to date version: dl.twrp.me/falcon). However, there is already a moving line on across the screen when I enter recovery mode. When I boot the stock ROM there is no line. Do you know why I have this line with the latest TWRP?

Comment: @PeterRabbit New TWRP is incompatible with old bootloader, and old TWRP vice versa.